# Excel trouble - how to transfer 15 min data to 10 min data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big Excel sheet with data taken from the sensors from one windfarm.

It is in one column, one below the other, just a clean numbers, integer (example 1435). Those columns represent data from every 15 minutes.

I need to get the data from it and transform it to 10 min data.

My idea was to divide it by 3 (get 5 min data) and just add two of those.

But I need the formula in excel which does that in the other column.

- So takes the first column
- divide it by 3,
- put it in the column next to it,
- copy it in 2 more rows below
- then repeat the procedure but with the other value in the 15 min data, below the first one.

I hope it makes sense,
much appreciated for any assistance

Comment: Please post the code from your previous approaches. What have been wrong?

Comment: I think you should post your sample data

Comment: I hope this will help https://postimg.org/image/a3m54hf19/

Comment: Please [edit] your post, and post the image in the question

Comment: I would have thought that you should be doing an interpolation to get the 10 minute values, e.g. the 10-minute value would be 1/3 the 0 minute value plus 2/3 of the 15 minute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create some simple loops.

```
Sub tenmindata()

Dim lastRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = 3
For i = 3 To lastRow
    For k = 1 To 3
        Cells(j, 7) = Cells(i, 3).Value / 3
        j = j + 1
    Next k
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question right but try this:

```
=A1/3*2
```

Post that in the column next to your data and doubleclick the small black dot:

https://abload.de/img/excelbwbzz.png

Comment: It is not that simple I am afraid. https://postimg.org/image/a3m54hf19/